Turned away on first day of the job
My brother was taken on by a well known company, went through 3 interview Zoom calls, vetting etc. and was offered the job. He turned up on the start date to be told you are not on the list. HR said someone from another branch from HR had revoked his job offer. This person bullied my brother when he was 17 years old, so was forced out of the work place. He managed to get a job at another branch only for this man to be able to cancel his job.
What can my brother do? Every time he rings the number he has, he gets nowhere. Either he can’t understand the person on the phone or they say HR have the last say with employing people.

If there is chance that actual is discrimination involved (which requires your  brother to be in a protected class) your brother should talk to a local labor lawyer. Laws and rules vary greatly around the world so without a location tag we really can't give any further advise.

“How can this be right” - Life isn’t fair. HR employees are human, and it sounds like, your brother was ultimately not hired. “This man works for HR, what can my brother do?” - Even if your brother is part of a protected class, not hiring someone because you don like them, isn’t disallowed. At this point your brother should move on, your brother could fight not being hired, but to what point?

Very sorry to hear and its definitely not fair but there's not a lot that he could do, its a case of very bad luck that this other guy works in HR. Even if he somehow went over his head if this bully has it in for your brother he can make his life very difficult and not worth it.  Consider it a bullet dodged.

What is the country?

As Mark says, the country matters very much.  In the UK, for example, the employer is not allowed to withdraw an unconditional job offer after it's been made and accepted.  Nor are they allowed to withdraw a conditional offer once it's been accepted and the conditions have been met (same source).  If this happened in the UK, an employment lawyer is your brother's next port of call.

Where do you live? In europe you cannot do this without at least a pay for the first month: you have a contract signed (either verbally or in paper) so if you can prove that a company needs to follow up on that, which is normally 4 weeks initially.

@paul23 from what I read the "brother" probably didn't have a signed contract yet, was expecting to sign on his first day (not that unusual). That means there's no recourse for him. I've had a similar situation where I got a job offer from my (intended) future department head (approved by the CEO) but the head of HR felt he was sidelined and retracted it. Luckily that happened well in advance of my starting date, but it was still a bummer.

@jwenting this is heavily location-dependent. In the UK signed offer letters are also legally binding contracts (or at least, create an implicit contract) and so, as MadHatter mentions in his comment the brother would seem to have access to legal remedies and should consult a lawyer

@paul23 Europe is not one country. Even if you restrict it to EC countries, there is still a lot of significant variation in employment law between countries.

You can always try to go in one level higher. I would think that your hiring manager would be very unhappy with this. There are situations where yes, the company can do this, but one particular company employee can't. The whole story is strange, so your HR person may have some explaining to do (to their manager).

"Either he can’t understand the person on the phone" Can you elaborate on what this means? Also, how do you know that the alleged bully is the one who cancelled the job offer? Is that an inference on being told "someone from another branch" and assuming that this must be the alleged bully because you know they work in HR at another branch?

@Donald: Given that OP's brother was offered this job, the alleged bully's actions do not seem to align with at least some one people in this company. Your advice of "roll over and take it" effectively empowers anyone to act as a bully if the expectation is that the target is told that it's better to give in than it is to fight it. This doesn't fix the issue, it perpetuates it.

@Donald except as stated multiple times in this thread, in many parts of the world a signed offer letter is legally binding, and so what happened is illegal. We don't have the information yet to say whether they should contact a lawyer or not, but it certainly isn't true that we know that what happened wasn't illegal

@Tristan - Author should clarify that aspect in that case

Close voters, what on earth is "company specific" about this? There are three answers here that address this question perfectly, without focusing on a specific company

Agree with the other answers that your brother should assume they're not getting this job.
But I think they should reach out anyway.
Something like an email to the following people:
The Hiring Manager, The Manager/Head of HR at the branch they were joining, Manager/Head of HR at the branch the HR guy works at, Regional Head of HR, General Manager of the location you were joining.
Subject line something like:

Discrimination and Abuse of Power by John Smith, HR Admin at [Location]

to get their attention
Then a very short email (written from the perspective of your brother):

I was hired to join [location] on [Date].
HR employee John Smith at completely unrelated branch [Z], who knows me and has personally attacked me in the past, removed that offer in the system  without notification.
I didn't find out until I turned up for my first day of work.
I wanted to reach out to all of you to let you know what your employee is doing. And because I do still want to work at [Location] and I'm hoping we can resolve this amicably.
Yours Sincerely,

etc
This all assumes the employee did this without approval/authorisation. If they just raised an internal objection "I know this guy and I don't think we should hire him" then your odds go way down. But given there was no notification, I think there's a chance they didn't do it via authorised channels.
So I wouldn't give it great odds of succeeding, but I think there's a chance. And that's a whole lot better than being unemployed.

@infinitezero That's fair. You're probably right. If the goal is to try and get the job anyway then it doesn't help. I'll edit it.

I like this answer (+1) because it is professional and the company may actually appreciate such feedback; And even maybe go ahead with the hiring (who knows)

Many will disagree with me here, but I would leave out the "who knows me and has personally attacked me in the past" part. While true, it colors the letter with an opinion of a complainer rather than focusing on the facts-- and companies don't want to hire complainers, because they cause problems in the future.

NO! HR employee John Smith at completely unrelated branch [Z], who knows me and has personally attacked me in the past, removed that offer in the system without notification. NO! Sending something like this could open the OP's brother to a libel lawsuit from John Smith. The OP does not have evidence of anything, just someone telling him that (who might no be willing to corroborate that in a trial). Thread carefully.

Do not personally state that John Smith has done anything unethical or against the company's interests, unless you have evidence. Just state that the offer was removed, and that you are worried because John Smith works there. Let management check the records, if they are interested in the issue (even if they believe the OP's brother and do not like these actions, they might decide that the cost of punishing John Smith is not worth the effort).

If you are going to make personal allegations: 1. Lawyer up. 2. Make sure, check and double check the allegations are valid, true and provable in court.

Did your brother have a signed Job offer and or Contract?
If the answer is Yes, then there may be some grounds for recourse. However as others have said, in most countries, within the fist X number of days of employment the rules around dismissal are a lot more flexible.
There may be grounds for a legal argument of bad faith on the side of the company... But to prove that would be very difficult (and when it comes to lawsuits difficult = expensive).
The other issue is you have to look at this from the Companies point of View:

Candidate interviewed
Candidate was accepted
Internal Staff member raised concerns about Candidate
Offer was withdrawn

That is, from a legal point of view, completely acceptable for the Company to do this.
At the point, the best thing your brother could do would be to write a review on the likes of Glassdoor stating their situation and let other potential candidate beware.

Assuming the HR guy did actually raise a formal objection. Rather than, say, going into the HR system and removing the offer themselves without proper authorisation. Given the lack of notification, I think there's a decent chance it may have been the latter.

@Kaz - that is a good point, but if they are senior enough and have unilateral hiring and firing power - then they wouldnt need to. They would only need to say: I have worked with this person previously and do not think it is in the best interest of the company that they be an employee.

Right, sure. But there's a chance that maybe users have system permissions which they shouldn't, but which haven't been a problem before so have never been fixed. As in, they can just go into the database and change the status of an application. I'm basing all of this on the fact that the application seemingly went from accepted to denied, but in a way that didn't generate some kind of email/notification. Which doesn't seem like normal system behaviour.

@Kaz Even so, he was probably just violating company policy, not the law, so it would be up to company management to take punitive action, if they desire. But if upper management is buddies with him, there may be no repercussions.

The best thing your brother can do is to write this company off and start looking for a job elsewhere.
Even in countries with strong worker protections, like in the EU, it is common to have a probation period in the employment contract. During such a probation period, both parties can very easily terminate the contract, basically for no reason at all. This is intended for the company and the employee to find out if they really are as good a fit as they thought after the interviews, but it unfortunately also gives bad actors an opportunity, as shown in your brother's case.
In countries with weak worker protections, contracts can also be terminated for no reason at all.

Disagree with this. Yes, the company does have that right. And if they wanted to hide behind it they could. But given the lack of notification it doesn't sound like the HR guy actually got the offer revoked properly, but did something like personally going into the system and removing it themselves. Which would mean they were acting beyond their authority and the company might reverse it if the right people were made aware of the situation.

@Kaz We don't know that. The HR person may have gone to the hiring manager and arrange a revocation with them. Or other possibilities. As Bart mentions, if this is the EU the easy way would have been to terminate him on the first (or whatever) day of his probation period. Removing someone from the database, in more serious companies, is not something you can do on a whim.

In Germany (an example of a country with strong worker protection), you can terminate the contract during probation, but you have to do so in writing and there is a 2 weeks notice period. So, if you lay off an employee on the day he is supposed to start, you owe them two weeks of wages, and you can't do it by saying "you're not on the list".
